# Selector issue in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I have the following HTML code to implement pagination.

```
<ul>
  <li class="active">
    <a class="paging" id="page_1" href="">1</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a class="paging" id="page_2" href="#">2</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a class="paging" id="page_3" href="#">3</a>
  </li>
```

I need to execute a block of javasript code when the user clicks on the page numbers.

I tried out the following

```
  $('.paging').click(function () {
    alert('test');
  });
```

But the alert message is not getting displayed.

What's wrong in my code?

Comment: wrap it in dom ready..

Comment: @AnoopJoshi `$('.paging')` not sufficient?

Comment: That depend on where you have place the script. If your script is in head tag, you should wrap it in dom ready. If you script is placed after those elements, you needn't use dom ready.

Comment: May I know the shorthand method of `$(document).ready()`?

Comment: @RandomUser, Read Docs http://api.jquery.com/ready/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to prevent default behaviour of anchor tag and it is better to wrap this script inside `document.ready` :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.paging').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        alert('test');
      });
   });
```

**[Working JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4HgV2/15/)**

Comment: after clicking I am getting redirected to `/#`

Comment: are you able to see alert()? have you added e in function(e)?

Comment: I added function(e) but not able to see the alert()

Comment: just console the length of selector `$('.paging')`. If may happen that selectors are not selecting any elements.

Comment: @BhushanKawadkar I did everything that you asked me to but still not working!

Comment: @RandomUser, check console error. This is working in provided jsfiddle.

Comment: @BhushanKawadkar, my apologies, since I am working with partial views the script wasn't working.. now I found out the problem. Thanks for your time and effort, I appreciate it.

Comment: @BhushanKawadkar I have another double how can I call the same function with `ID` instead of `Class`? the ID's are unique how can I call the function?

Comment: @RandomUser, you can use start with selector http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/ Replace  $('.paging') with $('[id^=page_]')

Answer (score 1):

hope this will help!

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.paging').click(function(){
    alert('test');
});
});
</script>
```